# Client and Server Side

Tags: crystal-reports

What is Client-Side reporting?

What is Server-Side Reporting?

How can I achieve those through Crystal Report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following question. It pertains even though it is based on SSRS.

[Using client side reporting vs. server side reporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137422/using-client-side-reporting-vs-server-side-reporting)